# sanitize unicode from json

Tags: python, python-3.x

how do I properly remove unicode so I can load the json

```
data = json.loads(json_string)
```

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 72 (char 71)

```
{"user": {"user_id": 455830511, "username": "dualipa_384", "name": "Dua\xa0Lipa", "private": false, "verified_user": false, "avatar_url": "https://uploads.cdn.triller.co/v1/avatars/455830511/1619366527_avatar.jpg", "profile_cover_url": "None", "dm_registered": true, "storefront_url": "None", "creator_status": false, "contributor_status": false, "user_uuid": "bce20042-a143-4caf-adbc-6b39bbb2d30a", "about_me": "Go stream my new album Future Nostalgia The Moonlight Edition❤️\ndualipa.co/weregood-video", "auto_confirmed": true, "instagram_handle": "@dualipa", "instagram_verified": false, "soundcloud_url": "None", "button_text": "None", "button_text_color": "None", "button_background_color": "None", "button_url": "None", "follower_count": 0, "followed_count": 55, "verified": true, "failed_age_validation": false, "has_snaps": false, "profile_type": "public", "blocking_user": false, "blocked_by_user": false, "followed_by_me": "false", "follower_of_me": "false", "subscription": {"is_subscribed": false}}, "status": true}
```

I have tried to do the following but it did not work

```
json_string = json_string.replace(u'\xa0', u'')
json_string = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", json_string)
```

Comment: Fix the code that produced the non-JSON in the first place.

Comment: @KellyBundy cannot control the json its coming from a third party website

Comment: Let them know about their bug so they can fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this how it worked for me

```
import json
import unicodedata

json_string = json.loads(json.dumps(json_string))
json_string = json_string.replace("\"false\"", "\"False\"").replace("false", "\"False\"").replace("true", "\"True\"").replace("\n", " ")
json_string = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", json_string)
json_string = json_string.replace(u'\xa0', u'')
json_string = json_string.replace('\n', r'\n')
            
data = json.loads(json_string)

print(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a newline character within a string. JSON does not allow line breaks withing strings. Replace the line break with an escape sequence:

```
json.loads(json_string.replace('\n', r'\n'))
```

Comment: Where do you see a newline character?

Comment: @KellyBundy Right here: `"...The Moonlight Edition❤️\ndualipa.co..."`. The fact that you could not see it does not mean it is not there.

Comment: That's not a newline yet. It's a backslash character followed by an 'n' character. [Demo](https://tio.run/##TZBLTsNAEET3PkXLG4NEQiLHkoWUHZ8NsGIZyeowHbvReNqaj0OEOAMnYMchOA8X4AhmnI/ErvRKqq6ubucbMXnZ2WF4cWIq5y2bGpZgsyx7S4Mjm17BQVSsol4URZnPivn8AvbUYEsRpyqg5g6rvFyk0Trh64CrV5zdR2vEneUe/ehsUDuKpCfLGyZVHW@dOK4l@OoQcicQixG20O7A0BZQr0MLt8EHS/AozqOuGeGpIXgQMZrrxsONYs9ifj6/fr8/VuZYcPosl1uyVIuoSc@KJH2PvyYJt51YD@MMiUKPcYRRT7Wgcmf/1jkfhj8) reproducing their exact error message, for the reason they've already identified.

Comment: @KellyBundy Wrong. It is a single character `\n` which is a line break.

Comment: No. It **would** be after the JSON-parsing, if that weren't prevented by the **actual** issue.

Comment: @KellyBundy I am not going to debate with you. Please learn about escape characters.

Comment: Please learn about strings, particularly raw string literals. You're flat out wrong.

Comment: @KellyBundy The string is not raw.

Comment: Or if you're really not able to do it with code, just copy&paste their "JSON" into https://jsonlint.com/ and you'll see the problem really is the `\xa0`, **not** the `\n`.